# DataFrame stores column of object as NaNs

Tags: pandas, vector

DataFrame stores NaNs instead of column of vectors

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": [4,5,6]}, index=["one", "two", "three"])
s = pd.Series([(i*10, i*11, i*12) for i in df["a"]], dtype=object)
```

Here the series is what I need it to be (contains a vectors).
But putting it together it only stores NaNs

```py
df.loc[:, "c"] = s
#       a   b   c
#one    1   4   NaN
#two    2   5   NaN
#three  3   6   NaN
```

Comment: What is `maxShear_vec` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If indices are not exactly same in `Series` and `DataFrame` got NaNs, because indices don't align.

Solution is same indices in `s.index` like `df.index`:

```
s = pd.Series([v / np.linalg.norm(v) for v in maxShear_vec],dtype='object'),index=df.index)

df["maxShear_vec"] = s
```

Also I think `dtype='object'` should be omited:

```
s = pd.Series([v / np.linalg.norm(v) for v in maxShear_vec],index=df.index)

df["maxShear_vec"] = s
```

Comment: wow that's it. Great! I'll reformulate question that is useful for other people